# Is the Incenter always "below" the middle point of an angle bisector segment in a triangle?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

Let $ABC$ be any triangle. Segment $\overline{CD}$ bisects angle $\angle ACB$, and segment $\overline{EB}$ bisects angle $\angle ABC$. These segments meet at the point $I$ (the incenter of the triangle). Prove that the middle point of $\overline{CD}$ is between $C$ and $I$.

Here's an image of where the incenter should be located in relation with the *angle bisector segment's* middle point (that means the section of the angle bisector that's inside of the triangle). What I want to know is why such points cannot be arranged in the order vertex-incenter-middle point.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in the standard notation we obtain:  $$\frac{CI}{ID}=\frac{BC}{BD}=\frac{a}{\frac{ac}{a+b}}=\frac{a+b}{c}>1$$

Comment: Nice +1 ........

Comment: Angle-bisectors meet at $I$. So, by the sine rule, $\frac{CI}a=\frac{\sin CBI}{\sin BIC}=\frac{ID}{BD}$ so $\frac{CI}{ID}=x=\frac{BC}{BD}$. Similarly, $\frac{AC}{AD}=x$. So $\frac{a+b}c=x$ whence your results.

Comment: @Rosie F Yes, of course, but firstly I like to try to solve without trigonometry.